# Building a dynamic join expression with calculations

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes - one is my data `df`, and the other is filters that need to be applied to the data `filterDF`, i.e.

**Data**

```
+---------+--------+-----------+
|FirstName|LastName|        SSN|
+---------+--------+-----------+
|     John|   Smith|123-12-1234|
|   Marsha|   Smith|321-32-4321|
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

and

**Filters**

```
+---------+--------+-----------+
|FirstName|LastName|        SSN|
+---------+--------+-----------+
|      Jon|   Smith|123-22-1234|
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

The search filters 1) are dynamic 2) need to be somewhat fuzzy (I am attempting to calculate the levenshtein distance). So someone could just search by first name, or by multiple criteria - and the search represented by the above scenario should return John Smith's row. I am looking for the best way to implement this functionality in Spark Scala (to which I am relatively new). Currently, I am able to successfully filter by an arbitrary number of criteria... if I hardcode in the filters:

```
val joinExpr = levenshtein(df("FirstName"), filterDF("FirstName")) < 4 && levenshtein(df("LastName"), filterDF("LastName")) < 4 && levenshtein(df("SSN"), filterDF("SSN")) < 4

val joined = df.join(
  filterDF,
  joinExpr
)
```

but, I have been unsuccessful in dynamically generating this expression.. I've tried:

```
val joinExpr = selects.map(v => levenshtein(df(v), filterDF(v)) < 4).mkString(" && ")
```

Where `selects` is a list of the columns to filter by - this doesn't work as the expression is just a string, and gets interpreted as if it's supposed to be a column.

Just doing:

```
val joinExpr = selects.map(v => levenshtein(df(v), filterDF(v)) < 4)
```

.... doesn't even compile.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Is there a way to dynamically build the join expression that I am looking for?
2. Is there a more effective way of accomplishing this functionality other than a join? I have tried building a filter but ran into similar issues...